# next button for listview

Tags: android, listview

My first activity contains a ListView that's getting a list of items from a database.
And in the OnClickListener, there is a new activity that's open getting all information related to the question from the database, I'm putting them in Intent extras and getting them in the next activity:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                String quest = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                int pos = lst.getCheckedItemPosition();

                Intent inte = new Intent(view.getContext(),Reponse.class);




                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ ModelHelper.TABLE_QUESTION + " WHERE " + ModelHelper.KEY_QUESTION + " = ? ",new String[] {quest});
                if (cursor != null)
                    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    String repA = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ModelHelper.KEY_PROFIL_WAITEDANSWER));
                    String cible = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ModelHelper.KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE));
                    String plan = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ModelHelper.KEY_PLANACT));
                    int ID = cursor.getColumnIndex(ModelHelper.KEY_ID_QUESTION);

                    inte.putExtra("question", quest);
                    inte.putExtra("repo", repA);
                    inte.putExtra("cible", cible);
                    inte.putExtra("plan", plan);
                  //  inte.putExtra("id", ID);
                    // inte.putExtra("pos", pos);


                    startActivity(inte);
                    finish();
```

In the info activity, it's simple and I could get the information from the database, here's the code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String question = intent.getStringExtra("question");
        String repo = intent.getStringExtra("repo");
        String cible = intent.getStringExtra("cible");
        String plan = intent.getStringExtra("plan");
        final int[] ID = {0};
        ID[0] = intent.getIntExtra("ID", ID[0]);
        int pos = 0;
        pos = intent.getIntExtra("pos",pos);

        txtq.setText(question);
        txtr.setText(repo);
        txtc.setText(cible);
        txtp.setText(plan);
```

I want to add a button NEXT that makes appear the next item in the list by refreshing the same page without going back to the list and click again.
I tried to get the position too with the intent and tried to set a new OnClickListener in the button to set the position = position +1, but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**

for that, you have to pass the entire list to next activity so you can directly do next item in the list by refreshing the same page without going back.

**Second solution.**

You have to separately apply query for next info page click on the next/previous button.

Comment: I have to create a ListView in the next page? or just as I did for the intent Extras?

Comment: you have to pass entirely `quest` list to next activity with a position which you click.

Comment: int pos =0;
         pos = intent.getExtras().getInt("i");

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go through the sql Queries

```
select * from table where key=primaryKey limit Page_Limit offset Start_From
```

You need to change `limit` and `offset` on select of list limit.

Comment: the Query is parametrable, I mean the user is choosing how much to display

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question, this part is working already.